# jquery update total based on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where based on checkbox total value will be updated

Here is my form

```
<label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="23">SEO                             
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="34">XYZ 
    </label>                                
    <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="45">Logo Design                                  
    </label>


    <span class="product-price" id="total" >45</span>
```

jQuery I have used

```
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
        var val = parseFloat(this.value),
            totalVal = parseFloat($('#total').val());
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#total').val((totalVal + val).toFixed(2));
        } else {
            $('#total').val((totalVal - val).toFixed(2));
        }
    });
```

But nothing get updated.What could be the possible Error?
Any solution please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Span attribute doesn't have a `val()` property but `text()`

```js
 

    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
            var val = parseFloat(this.value),
                totalVal = parseFloat($('#total').text());
            if (this.checked) {
                $('#total').text((totalVal + val).toFixed(2));
            } else {
                $('#total').text((totalVal - val).toFixed(2));
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="23">SEO                             
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="34">XYZ 
    </label>                                
    <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="45">Logo Design                                  
    </label>


    <span class="product-price" id="total" >45</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it:

```
if (this.checked) {
            $('#total').val((totalVal + val).toFixed(2));
        } else {
            $('#total').val((totalVal - val).toFixed(2));
        }
```

to

```
if (this.checked) {
            $('#total').text((totalVal + val).toFixed(2));
        } else {
            $('#total').text((totalVal - val).toFixed(2));
        }
```

as `span` do not have a `value` attribute, the text you see is the `text` attribute associated with that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function .simply add with checked values only on each time check or uncheck .no need subtraction for below method

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
var tot=0;
$('input:checked').map(function(a){
 tot += parseInt($(this).val()) 
})
  $('#total').val(tot.toFixed(2));
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="23">SEO                             
    </label>
<label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="34">XYZ 
    </label>
<label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="45">Logo Design                                  
    </label>
    <input id="total">
```